# How do I get the GUI to recognize that my output is actually set up?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, output, pi

The output on GPIO 27 is connected to a dc motor. The code is to get the motor to start from a GUI using, tkinter button widget. When I run the program RC5 the motor works fine. When I run the GUI to start the motor it says the GPIO is not set to output.

After adding the GPIO section to the GUI it no longer produces the error that GPIO isn't set up. Now it won't recognize the pulse from the raspberry pi. I've tried defining it in the GUI but it puts out the same error.

The error code is what follows:

```
'''
Run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RGUI.py", line 242, in <module>
    motor_run()
  File "RGUI.py", line 207, in motor_run
    running = R.loop()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/CODES/RC5.py", line 67, in loop
    motor(value)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/CODES/RC5.py", line 56, in motor
    p.ChangeDutyCycle(95)
NameError: name 'p' is not defined
'''

'''
#The following code is for motor_run below to connect the GPIO pins

GPIO17 = 17
GPIO22 = 22
GPIO27 = 27

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(GPIO17, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(GPIO22, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(GPIO27, GPIO.OUT)

p = GPIO.PWM(17 , 1000) # create PWM and set Frequency to 1KHz      
'''
```

```
        #The following code is to run/stop the motor
        
        #running = True
        
        def motor_run():
            running = R.loop()
            
                
        def on_start():
            motor_run = True
            
        def on_stop():
            motor_run = False   
            
        
        frame5 = LabelFrame(main_canvas, text="Run Program", padx=5, pady=5, font=("Times", 20))
        frame5.grid(row=3, column=0)
        
        main_canvas.create_window((0,630), window=frame5, height=150, width= 200, anchor="s")
        
        Button_run=Button(frame5, text="run", command=on_start, bg="white", fg="black", padx=5, pady=5, font=("Times", 16))
        Button_run.grid(row="2", column="0")
        
        Button_stop=Button(frame5, text="stop", command=on_stop,  bg="white", fg="black", padx=5, pady=5, font=("Times", 16))
        Button_stop.grid(row="2", column="1")
    
    #The following is from the code RC5
    #set up GPIO pins
        GPIO.setup(17 , GPIO.OUT) # connected to pwm
        GPIO.setup(22 , GPIO.OUT) # connect to In2
        GPIO.setup(27 , GPIO.OUT) # connected to In1
    
        p = GPIO.PWM(17 , 1000) # creat PWM and set Frequence to 1KHz
        p.start(0)
    
    
    def motor(ADC):
        value = ADC 
        if (chan0 > -16384):  # turn clockwise
            GPIO.output(27, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(22, GPIO.LOW)
            print("Run")
            p.ChangeDutyCycle(95)
        elif (chan0 < -16348):
            GPIO.output(27, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(22, GPIO.LOW)
            print("Run Slow")
            p.ChangeDutyCycle(75)
    # function calls
    on_stop()
    on_start()
    motor_run()
    update_value()
    update_bat_1()
    update_bat_2()
    update_gen1()
    #main()
    main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Posting screenshots is frowned upon here when it only involves text. Please replace the screenshot with a copy an paste of the error text from your terminal.

Comment: You don't show where you call `main_canvas.mainloop()`.  Remember that must be the end of your program; `mainloop` will not return until the window is closed.  If you call that BEFORE you set up the GPIO pins, then the error message is exactly correct.  Do all of your setup before you call `mainloop`.

Comment: The error tells you that `motor_run()` is executed before `GPIO.setup(27 , GPIO.OUT)`.

Comment: I'll correct the screenshot immediately, and post the code where I call the mainloop.

Comment: If it's calling motor_run before the GPIO. setup how do I set it to work at the same time?

Comment: Just call those `GPIO.setup(...)` before running `motor_run()`.

Comment: I edited the code by adding a section for GPIO setup in the GUI. Now it bypasses the output error. There's a new error code referring to the python code I'm calling from, it's posted above.

Comment: I think you need to move the line `p = GPIO.PWM(17 , 1000)` into `motor()` function.

Comment: So with help, I realized later that I wasn't calling the function into my GUI from the other program. Now that it is being called the function isn't connected to the button.